# Laptop Docking Station not detecting HDMI Monitor when connected via type C cord

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, power-supply, hdmi, hardware-failure

I have a Lenovo Legion laptop and a dell monitor. Also have seperate keyboard and mouse which i use for gaming.

I bought the Dock by Honeywell(https://amzn.eu/d/1gtN4ZN), which comes with a small Type C to Type C connector. It was too short to use comfortably, so i bought a longer Type C connector by Honeywell itself(https://amzn.eu/d/cKTUpv7).

Dock has Keyboard & Mouse USB, Monitor HDMI out and Laptop is connected to the dock via Type C port.

This setup for a few months and suddenly, the monitor is not detecting the data. The keyboard and mouse are working, just the monitor is not detecting the signal. I tried using the shorter Type C wire which came with the dock to check if HDMI was working, the monitor works when the shorter wire is used to connected the dock and laptop.

So i again bought another type c to type c connector, thinking the longer wire was damaged. I bought this connector (https://amzn.eu/d/d8TSNWS). But that also has the same issue as the longer type c connector.

Does the power of the connector has some relationship with the data transfer ? Both connectors which are not working are 60W, will that be the reason the smaller type c connector is working but the longer ones does not work?

Comment: How much longer was the Type-C cable? USB has finite length limits when your talking about non-fiber cables.

Comment: "Data Transfer" <> Video.  Neither of those cables has enough bandwidth to support video to a monitor (at least HD video).  The Honeywell is only 470MBPS and the Portronics is 1Gbps.  You want to look for an actual USB-C to USB-C Monitor cable.

Comment: Thanks, let me check it. Do you have any reference for Type-C to Type-C mointor cable?

Comment: Can this be used for the purpose ? https://www.amazon.in/Monitor-Charging-Compatible-Smartphone-Nintendo/dp/B08KSSJ9NR/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8&th=1